# Genius API Display Lyrics in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, integration

How do I fetch the lyrics of all too well (10 minute version) in HTML using the Genius Lyrics API ?
URL: https://genius-song-lyrics1.p.rapidapi.com/search/

HTML code:

```
<div id="choices">
    <button class="integration-btn lyrics-btn">
        <p>Lyrics</p>
    </button>
    <button class="integration-btn">
        <p>Other Albums</p>
    </button>
    <button class="integration-btn">
        <p>Related Artists</p>
    </button>
</div>
<pre id="lyrics-content"></pre>
```

I want to display the output in lyrics-content (using javascript) but I don't know how to do it...
What do I need to do to get the lyrics of the song?

Comment: Are you sure `rapidapi.com` is the official API for Genius.com? Their documentation page doesn't reference them at all... https://docs.genius.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="choices">
    <button class="integration-btn lyrics-btn">
        <p>Lyrics</p>
    </button>
</div>
<pre id="lyrics-content"></pre>

<script>
    const lyricsButton = document.querySelector('.lyrics-btn');
    const lyricsContent = document.getElementById('lyrics-content');

    lyricsButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const songTitle = 'Name of the song';
            const response = await fetch(`https://genius-song-lyrics1.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${songTitle}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY'
                }
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Error API request');
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.response.hits.length > 0) {
                const lyrics = data.response.hits[0].result.lyrics;
                lyricsContent.textContent = lyrics;
            } else {
                lyricsContent.textContent = 'No lyrics found.';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Errore:', error);
            lyricsContent.textContent = 'Error fetching lyrics';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Remember to include this JavaScript code within your HTML document, preferably within a  tag before the closing  tag. Also, ensure that your API key is kept secure and not publicly exposed in your code.